# Valid characters for each url segment?

Tags: parsing, http, url, ftp, uri

I'm currently looking for a list of valid URL characters for each segment.
By segments I mean:

```
Scheme     Username   Password       Domain       Port        Path          Querystring     Fragment
 http  ://   user   :   pass   @  foo.abcd.com  :  80  /  bla/index.htm  ?  abc=123&x=z  #   qwerty
```

(I hope this makes it clear.)

In case you are wondering, I need this information to write a very efficient URL parser.

edit:
I think I also need to know the rules for the starting and ending characters for each segment.

Answer (score 2):

How about consulting the specification? See http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc3986.html

Comment: The spec on the official IETF website is http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986 (HTML version).

Comment: Remy: (a) tools.ietf.org is *not* the official IETF websitee; the *official RFC* is http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt (have fun with the plain text :-), (b) that being said, the HTML in the URI that I posted matches the "actual" spec.

Comment: (a) http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt (b) Personally, I prefer to use RFC URLs that are from the ietf.org domain directly, that's all.